# android camera recording video with special ISO value

Tags: android, camera, iso, mediarecorder

My app is about capture video by custom camera.It only has to capture the video of a LED photo frame. The led frequency is 1000 HZ. just like this
[image]
I use these code to init the camera and start preview. The key parameter is ISO value.
[image]
The screen preview like this:We can see the **black stripe**!
[image: preview]
And then,I init the MediaRecorder like this:
[image]
When the MediaRecorder is run the start() function,**The blank stripe** in screen is dismiss.**The most important picture is dismiss.** the picture like this:
[image]
**Why It will dismiss.This is My First Question.**
And Then,When the MediaRecord is stop by invoked the MediaRecorder.stop(),the **Black Stripe** is appear again, like the first and third picture above.

After this,I set the AutoExposureLock parameter to true. lock the exposure by the under code.

```
p.setAutoExposureLock(true);
camera.setParameters(p);
```

And then We start the MediaRecorder to recording the LED photo frame by the code in Picture 4 above once angin. The Black Stripe will be recorded in the video until MediaRecorder.Stop().

In summary,

step 1 We set the ISO value,the screen preview is work with black stripe.

Step 2 When first time record is starting,The black stripe is dismiss.

Step 3 First time record is stop,the black stripe is appear again.

Step 4 Lock the exposure and start record again the black stripe will always appear during the whole recording process.

**I just want to record the video with black stripe at first time**,But now my app only can do it at second time.I was in trouble by this quesstion in several days.Has any one occus these situation before or know what is the answer of this?